# Designate on report if data listed is from table A or B

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, I'm doing homework and the question is asking me the following

> A representative from Northwind Traders will be in Germany. Management would like her to visit all German suppliers and customers while she is there. Provide a list of all suppliers and customers in Germany, including contacts and addresses. Designate on the report whether the company listed is a customer or a supplier.

The last part is what I am having trouble with, displaying if a company is a customer or supplier.

Comment: Northwind = homework.

Comment: Please add the recordsource of your report to the question

Answer (score 0):

The set equivalent of logical `OR` is `UNION` e.g.

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } UNION { 2, 3, 4 } = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

The relational model (RM) equivalent of logical `OR` is also `UNION`. All RM operators, the objects being operated on must be relations - google First Normal Form (1NF) for a formal definition. Additionally, `UNION` requires the two relations to be equivalent i.e. their set of attributes must be the same (by type and name); often the `RENAME` operator is required to satisfy this requirement e.g.

```
Suppliers ( SupplierName ) UNION Customers ( CustomerName )
```

wouldn't be valid but can be made valid using `RENAME` e.g.

```
( ( Suppliers RENAME ( SupplierName AS Name ) ) ( Name ) )
UNION
( ( Customers RENAME ( CustomerName AS Name ) ) ( Name ) )
```

If you need to retain the information about whether a name relates to a supplier or a customer then you can add a literal value e.g.

```
( ( Suppliers RENAME ( SupplierName AS Name ) ) ( Name, 'Supplier' AS Relationship ) )
UNION
( ( Customers RENAME ( CustomerName AS Name ) ) ( Name, 'Customer' AS Relationship ) )
```

Standard SQL supports all these operators but is much more strict about structure e.g. the attrributes must be projected in the same order. The equivalent of the last query:

```
SELECT SupplierName AS Name, 'Supplier' AS Relationship
  FROM Suppliers
UNION
SELECT CustomerName AS Name, 'Customer' AS Relationship
  FROM Customers
```